# Enthought Canopy Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, macos, opencv, enthought, canopy

I've installed Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 64-bit and it has OpenCV 2.4.2. When I `import cv2` I get the following error:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Foo/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Python
  Referenced from: /Users/Foo/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
  Reason: image not found
```

[This post suggests](https://mail.enthought.com/pipermail/enthought-dev/2013-May/032415.html) that the solution is to run `install_name_tool -change...` but I do not know what options to pass it, and am not familiar enough with dynamic libraries to understand the man page, so I turn here for help.

Comment: I take it you are using the Mac version or Linux version, not Windows, correct?

Comment: yes this is osx. I've tagged the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
install_name_tool -change @executable_path/../Python $HOME/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Python $HOME/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

Thanks to original author who also replied completing thread at link in the question.